# How do I count the number of words in a specific cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

The objective is to show a word-count in a cell next to a cell containing a paragraph, like so:

```
|                              text                                      |   word_count |
|------------------------------------------------------------------------|------------  |
|   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut ut.      |     120      |
|   Suspendisse a lacus elementum, auctor lorem et, convallis quam.      |              |
|   Mauris facilisis sollicitudin orci, sed auctor dui blandit sit amet. |              |
|   Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.        |              |
|   Nunc ut lacinia mauris. Pellentesque lobortis pretium convallis.     |              |
|   Cras in condimentum elit. Integer pellentesque nibh diam.            |              |
|   Praesent a erat molestie purus luctus malesuada volutpat.            |              |
|   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.             |              |
|   Suspendisse et lorem non neque sodales viverra et risus..            |              |               
|   Pellentesque tincidunt rhoncus enim sit amet tempor.                 |              |             
|   Pellentesque non leo non purus eleifend dapibus sit.                 |              |       
|   Sed fermentum lectus vel dapibus euismod. Aenean ante                |              |               
|   nisl, sagittis ut mauris sed, congue imperdiet lectus. Nam           |              |          
|   rutrum condimentum sapien a feugiat  amet a orci.                    |              |
```

Valid words are:

- formed using continuous strings of letters, or may contain hypthens, e.g. purpose-built
- a minimum of N characters long (which can be adjusted depending on the examiner)

What formula do I enter in the word_count cell?

**Work done so far:**

Just this: `=COUNTA(SPLIT(A2, ” “))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can also try:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(--(len(split(regexreplace(A1, "[^A-Za-z\-\s]"," "), " "))>2)))
```

where 2 is the minimum length of the word.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an (ugly) solution but at least it works I think

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1, "([^\s].{2}[^\s]*)|([^\s].*$)", "randomToken")," "))
```

Explain: with data `a asdad sadad dasdad asdad`

`REGEXREPLACE()` will check all matching pattern `([^\s].{2}[^\s]*)|([^\s].*$)` and replace it with `randomToken`(you can put whatever here)

`([^\s].{2}[^\s]*)|([^\s].*$)` match 3 any character and after that will stop if meet a space (Note that the minimum character allow is put inside the regex as n-1)

The result after `REGEXREPLACE` is `randomToken randomToken randomToken randomToken`

Then just `split` it and `counta`, we will have the result.

Hope it can help